# Error Twisted Module in Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, python-module

When tried to install Twisted for Python 3.6.3 it keeps on throwing a particular error :

```
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Tried install the Visual-Cpp-build tools but its a massive 4 + gigs download so is there any other way to do it .. Also I have all the redistributable.

Comment: Do you try Install Scrapy on Windows? You should find `.whl` package with Twisted and lxml for windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing **Scrapy** on **Windows** can be a real struggle. Some strange errors can occur.

That's why the  [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#installing-scrapy) recommands to use [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) for the scrapy installation. I think you should give it a try if you are working on **Windows**.

First you need to install Anaconda following this [tutorial](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-windows).

Then you just need to run this command `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`
 and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem 
what I did is install it manually

got to  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

and download suitable twisted version.

then

```
pip install Twisted-18.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

hope this solves for you too